# How to generate SQL if we are adding column in middle in table using liquibase

Tags: liquibase

Suppose in v1 I have a table

```
create table test1
{
col1 varchar2(10),
col2 varchar2(10),
col3 varchar2(10),
}
```

in version v2, there is request to add table in middle column `col1_2` like

```
create table test1
{
col1 varchar2(10),
col1_2 varchar2(30),
col2 varchar2(10),
col3 varchar2(10)
}
```

so does liquibase has ability to add generate table  of rebuild table?

Answer (score 0):

No, Liquibase can not do this in a generic way. You could drop and re-create the table, but that is probably not what you want to do. If you want to do something like this, you would need to do a SQL change that did something fairly complex. One way would be to create a new table with the columns in the order you want, and then copy the data from the old table to the new one, then drop the old table, and finally rename the new table to the correct name.

An easier way to do it might be with a view.

In general, the order of columns in a table should not be considered important.